# Average filter using CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm planning to build image processing using CUDA. To represent an image I use a matrix (values are randomly generated). I want to apply average filter to this matrix. The filter size I used is 3. Here is the code I have written. This works fine when the number (N = 10) is less than the block dimension size (BLOCK_DIM = 32). I tried with N=5 and BLOCK_DIM = 3. It works fine.

Why does this code result unexpected results (0 instead of average) when the BLOCK_DIM increases, how can I solve this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define BLOCK_DIM 32

__global__ void averageKernel (int *a, int *c) {
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int index = col + row * N;

    c[index] = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    if (row > 0 && col > 0 && col < N-1 && row < N-1 ) {  
        sum = sum + a[index - 1];
        sum = sum + a[index + 1];
        sum = sum + a[index - N-1];                
        sum = sum + a[index - N];                  
        sum = sum + a[index - N+1];                
        sum = sum + a[index + N-1];                
        sum = sum + a[index + N];                  
        sum = sum + a[index + N+1];                
        sum = sum + a[index];                      
        avg = sum/9;                            
    }
        c[index] = avg;

}

void printMatrix(int a[N][N] )
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[N][N], c[N][N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_c;

    int size = N * N * sizeof(int);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            a[i][j] = rand() % 256;
        }

    printf("Matrix A\n");
    printMatrix(a);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_DIM, BLOCK_DIM);
    dim3 dimGrid((N+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x, (N+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y);

    printf("dimGrid.x = %d, dimGrid.y = %d\n", dimGrid.x, dimGrid.y);

    averageKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Matrix c\n");
    printMatrix(c);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting "unexpected results", because your kernel is failing with out of bounds memory access. If you added [error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/681865) to your code and/or used `cuda-memcheck`, you would already know this.

The source of the problem is these two lines:

```
c[index] = 1;

....

c[index] = avg;
```

which are executed unconditionally, and which will produce out of bounds memory access when the number of threads you run exceeds the size of the output matrix. If you modify your kernel so those are only executed for threads inside the bounds of the output matrix, the problem should go away.